# Random unique binary matrices

Tags: r, matrix, combinations, permutation

I want Random BUT unique binary matrices of dimension n*n.

For example, if n = 5, then there are 2^(5*5) = 33554432 unique combinations (matrices), which is a HUGE number. I only need 1000. This is my current approach but it takes ALOT of time (which I can not afford because I need to increase the dimensions in future). And I feel it is redundant because in the end I am only selecting 1000 random combinations out of the full number. Any other approach to handle this? This is how I am currently doing it:

I start with a data frame of n*n variables, first row all 1s and second row all 0s:

```
 Length = 25
 m <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(rep(0, connections), rep(1, 
      connections)),ncol=25, byrow = TRUE))
```

m looks like this:

```
#V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20 V21 
#V22 V23 V24 V25
#1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
#0   0   0   0   0
#2  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   
#1   1   1   1   1
```

Next I get all the unique combinations using expand.grid

```
mFull = expand.grid(m) # This takes forever
```

And then I select 1000 random rows:

```
mRand = mFull[sample(1:nrow(mFull), 1000,)]
```

And after this I convert each row into a n*n matrix, for example, for 1st row:

```
mRand[1,]
#     V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20 
#V21 V22 V23 V24 V25
#21788869  1  1  0  1  1  1  0  0  1   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   
#0   1   1   0   1   0
```

Convert it to a matrix:

```
> matrix(mRand[1,], nrow = 5, byrow = TRUE)
 [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,] 1    1    0    1    1   
 [2,] 1    0    0    1    1   
 [3,] 1    0    0    0    0   
 [4,] 1    1    1    0    0   
 [5,] 1    1    0    1    0
```

Does anyone has a suggestion for a more efficient solution?

Comment: Generate 1000 binary matrices and then check to see if you have any duplicates. If you do generate some more. Repeat until they're all unique.  There is about a 98.5% chance that your initial selection of 1000 will be all unique when n=5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you just generate the matrices completely random and check for each new matrix if it already has been created. If not, discard it.

As long as the number of possible matrices is a lot bigger than the number of matrices needed this works well, otherwise it may be slow.

Example code:

```
randomMatrix <- function(n) matrix(as.numeric(runif(n^2) > 0.5), ncol = n)  # generates random binary square matrix of size n x n

m <- 1000  # number of matrices needed

res <- vector("list", m)  # stores the result
i <- 1  # index of next matrix

while (i <= m) {

  cand <- randomMatrix(5)
  ## check if the candidate is distinct from all matrices in res
  if (!any(sapply(res, function(x) identical(x, cand)))) {  
    res[[i]] <- cand
    i <- i + 1
  }

}
```

If you really run into speed problems (which I doubt) you could use some hashes to speed up compoarison. For example you could store the row- and column sums for each matrix and only test for equality if the sums coincide.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the number of possible matrices fits in an integer, you can encode each matrix as the binary representation of an integer. So if you sample integers without replacement and then turn those integers into binary matrices, you're done.

Here's a couple of functions:

```
binmat <- function(dec,n){
    matrix(as.integer(intToBits(dec)[1:(n*n)]),n,n)

}
rbinmats <- function(n,m){
    max = 2^(m*m)
    stopifnot(max < .Machine$integer.max)

    m_decimal = sample(max,n)-1

    lapply(m_decimal, binmat, n=m)

}
```

`binmat` works like this:

```
> binmat(123,3)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    1    1    0
[3,]    0    1    0
```

That's just the 9 bit binary representation of 123 (001111011) written as a matrix (backwards).

`rbinmats` just samples and creates random matrices of this form:

```
> rbinmats(4,3)
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    0    1
[2,]    0    1    0
[3,]    0    1    0

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    1    1    0
[3,]    1    1    1

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    0    1    0
[3,]    0    1    0

[[4]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    0    0
[2,]    0    0    1
[3,]    1    0    1
```

Here it is sampling 4 integers from 0 to  (2^9)-1, without replacement, and encoding them, so they will be unique.

5x5 seems to be the largest you can do in integers, since 2^(5*5) is less than max int, but 2^(6*6) isn't. Unless there's a way to do this with 64 bit numbers.

Comment: But I need to increase the number 5 to bigger numbers!

Comment: Then you can modify this approach by randomly selecting more than one integer for each matrix. You get 32 bits per integer. Two integers will get you 64 bits for anything up to an 8x8 matrix. The code would need some work but the general approach is sound. How big do you want?

Comment: Its a good idea. I dont know before hand how much i will really need in future. But I will definately give this a try.